# Why do I see messages from Little Snitch about apps connecting to outside IPs other than my VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn

[Little Snitch says Thunderbird wants to connect to an Outside IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufHgj.png), but I'm running a VPN (with Tunnelblick 3.8.4) - so shouldn't Little Snitch see all this sort of traffic as going to my VPN? ie.  is this leaking, or is Little Snitch seeing things coming out of the VPN as local traffic?

Answer (score 0):

No. Such apps as Thunderbird do not communicate with your VPN server, nor do they know about it. The only app which talks to the VPN server is the VPN client.

Instead, VPNs (unlike proxies) work at IP packet level. Thunderbird still contacts 40.101.121.18 as before, but the VPN client intercepts those IP packets before they leave your system and encapsulates them within a second IP packet with its own destination address.

Comment: OpenVPN and Tunnelblick work on [Layer 3](https://openvpn.net/faq/what-is-the-osi-layer-model/). What I want to confirm is that the message from Little Snitch is not an indication of leakage, but just an indication that Little Snitch is running higher up, where it cannot see the rerouting through the VPN.

Comment: This means they carry layer-3 packets (IP header only, no L2 header) – it _does not_ mean rerouting happens by changing the layer-3 destination address. Regular IP routes work by altering the L2 destination, not the L3 destination. So yes, it would be "Little Snitch is running higher up", because it's inspecting layer 3 and not L2. I think you were assuming one layer higher for both.

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the explanation. That makes sense.